# How can I pass Express session data to be rendered on every Pug/Jade template?

Tags: node.js, express, session, authentication, pug

I'm creating a simple session-based authentication on my site. I'm using `express-session` to make the server-side logic of login.

After I successfully log in on server-side, I want to show the logged user's email in every page.

I could pass on every page rendering in the following way:

```
router.get('/my-route', function(req, res, next) {
    ...
    res.render('my-page', {
        userId: user.email
    }

});
```

But there will be too much replicated code if I have more pages in my website.

There is a way to pass the session data to be rendered on every page by putting in my layout Pug/Jade template and other templates could extends that?

Like this (on `layout.jade`):

```
div(class='container')
    if (session.userId)
        br
        p
            | You are signed in as &nbsp;
            b #{session.userId}
            a(href='sign-out') Sign Out

    block content
```

And every page extends the layout with the user information:

```
extends layout

block content

    ...
```

Comment: Please add more detail?

Comment: I want to render the data on one template (in my case `layout.jade`) and make every page to extends that template, i couldn't find a way to pass this data by using the `res.render`, because it pass data to the specific template that will be rendered.

Comment: But if you have two file,you must use two render.

Comment: Ok, but there is a way that I can assure that I could access a variable on every page without passing from `res.render` every time I render some page, like it was a global variable? This is my question.

Comment: Now i understand you:)

Comment: There is no way;you must use res.render or res.send.

Comment: I think I can encapsulate the `res.render` in another method and add the session data there? It is not the prettiest one but is a solution :)